# Heroku- Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch. TooTallNate Websockets

Tags: java, heroku, websocket

I'm using a tootallnate websockets server listening for connections from a website.

**How do I make a connection to my server on heroku?**

When my website tries to connect at

```
wss://Heroku-Name-39329.herokuapp.com/
```

or

```
wss://Heroku-Name-39329.herokuapp.com:5000/
```

My heroku logs output.

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wss://Heroku-Name-39329.herokuapp.com request_id=4afca002-2078-439c-85dc-ad6ef7db50d2 fwd="207.244.77.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

And then(Still Heroku Logs)

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
Process exited with status 137
State changed from starting to crashed
State changed from crashed to starting
Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* v1.a1.server
```

My javascript logs

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://Heroku-Name-39329.herokuapp.com/:5000/' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed.
```

My Apps set within the server are.

```
String host = "";
int port = 5000;
```

My Procfile

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* v1.a1.server
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using this:

```
String host = "0.0.0.0";
int port = System.getenv("PORT");
```

On Heroku, you must bind to `0.0.0.0` and use the port assigned to your app, which is contained in the `$PORT` environment variable.

From the client, you will not need to specify a port, so only `wss://Heroku-Name-39329.herokuapp.com/` should be used (not the one with 5000).

Comment: I don't know where 0.0.0.0 came from instead of 127.0.0.1, but thank you!
[heroku kb](https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error)

Answer (score 24):

Heroku wants you to use a certain port.

Add this to your Procfile to get that port:

```
-Dserver.port=$PORT
```

So yours would look like this:
Procfile

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes/:target/dependency
```

Comment: Oh man, I am sending real good karma your side, in real life. I have been trying to fix this bug for 6 hours now.

Answer (score 4):

Into `application.properties` add:

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

then into Procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAR_OPTS
```

This should be enought.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku has its own env variable for its port number.  use this in the server.js file.

```
// included process.env PORT variable for herokus specific port needed to deploy
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
```

so if not using PORT it will use 8000.  heroku will use the PORT variable.
full file example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static('public'));
router.get('*',function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index'));
});

included process.env PORT variable for herokus specific port needed to deploy
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
    app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log('listening on port 8000');
    });
```

Comment: The question is about java, not javascript

Answer (score 2):

I might be late to the party but this helped me solve this problem, change the `application-prod.yml` and bootstrap-prod.yml to reflect the heroku registry location and add `-Dserver.port=$PORT` to the `Procfile` after the `$JAVA_OPTS` , then relaunch! :)