# How to deploy and access a Java WebSocket endpoint on Heroku without any additional frameworks

Tags: java, heroku, deployment, websocket, endpoint

I have followed this very basic tutorial for setting up a WebSocket endpoint in Java: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

Heroku, however, expects me to rely on Play Framework: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets

My question is: how could I deploy the same without any additional frameworks and what procedure should I go through in order to make things work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you had was this:

The tutorial you followed was made for the GlassFish Application Server but Heroku only supports Tomcat 8 and Jetty. See here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

But don't worry, I ported and tested the tutorial to run with Tomcat 8.

I also added the glassfish implementation of the javax.json specification.
(Make sure to download the implementation and not the spec interfaces only)
You can find it here: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/

I also noticed why maybe your index.html didn't work locally: I think it was because the WebSocket URL was hardcoded in the websocket.js file.
I have taken the liberty to fix this by making it dynamic.

Here is the complete NetBeans 8.0.2 project:
http://ray.hulha.net/WebsocketHome.zip

Here is the best way to create a war file from inside NetBeans 7 or 8:
[image]

**There is one catch however, the Tomcat 8 on Heroku is missing the websocket addon.**

But no worries, you can added it manually to the war file.
Here are the steps:

1. Download the Tomcat websocket addon here:
   http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.29/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.29.jar
2. The war file is really just a zip file. So I used [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to open the war file. Then navigate to the WEB-INF/lib folder inside the war file.
3. Copy the jar into the war. Drag and Drop the tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.29.jar into the lib folder of the war file inside 7-Zip.
4. Z-Zip will ask if you really want to copy the jar into the war file.
   Say Yes.

Here is the compiled war file complete with the tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.29.jar ready to deploy on Heroku:
http://ray.hulha.net/WebsocketHome.war

I used this command to deploy it:

```
heroku war:deploy WebsocketHome.war --app websockethome
```

**Make sure to replace the app name in the end with your app name.**

And here is the working result:
http://websockethome.herokuapp.com/

[image]

Comment: Also it seems the webapp-runner on Heroku does not support WebSockets. See this  for a way to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170817/websocket-working-on-localhost-but-not-heroku-updated

Comment: Did not work out as expected. I tried to build your project and deploy the resulting WAR to Heroku. Then, I deployed **your** WAR file. None of the two did the job.

Comment: Got it working ! You have to copy the tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.29.jar into the war file. The war file is just a zip file. I used 7-ZIP. Inside the WAR file you have to go into the WEB-INF/lib folder. Copy the jar into this folder. I downloaded tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.29.jar from here: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.29/ I also updated the war file on my server. Here is a working demo: http://websockethome.herokuapp.com/#

Comment: I added detailed steps for everything to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Ray! I will review/test your answer tomorrow.

Comment: We are getting close, but, alas, when I rebuild and redeploy my version (with tomcat-emded-websocket-8.0.29 in WEB-INF\lib), Heroku shows me its "Application Error" page if I try to access its (dummy) index.html. In other words, deployment works, everything else does not.

Comment: Are you on Skype ?

Comment: I am. When you are available?

Comment: I have no microphone on my PC.

Comment: Raymond, don't forget to mention that the JSON library JAR should be added too.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not require Play framework to use Websockets. That is just an example. As long as your app from the Oracle tutorial binds to `$PORT` it should work.

Comment: Having taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751071/heroku-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-90-seconds-of-launch-tootall it would seem that I need to bind the host to 0.0.0.0 also. Is that correct?

Comment: Could you please supply a link to a resource that describes the process of binding to 0.0.0.0? I simply cannot find anything relevant on that topic.

Comment: I have set up a bounty. You might be interested.

Comment: Are you able to run the Oracle example from the command-line (that is, not in the IDE)?

Comment: I have zero idea how to do that.

Comment: Do you have a WAR file generated by the IDE?

Comment: Yes, the WAR file exists and I know in which folder it resides in.

Comment: Try deploying it to heroku with `heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy` and then `heroku deploy:war yourapp.war`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169263/discussion-between-coderodde-and-codefinger).