# URI for connecting to Heroku WebSocket endpoint

Tags: java, heroku, websocket, endpoint

We have a Java web application at `http://ourapp.com` hosted at Heroku and the frontend of the app cannot connect to the WebSocket endpoint (`endpoint`) running in a Heroku dyno. We have tried these URIs:

1. `ws://ourapp.com/endpoint`
2. `ws://ourapp.com:80/endpoint`
3. `ws://ourapp.com:8080/endpoint`
4. `ws://ourapp.com:8084/endpoint`
5. `ws://ourapp.com:443/endpoint`
6. `wss://ourapp.com/endpoint`
7. `wss://ourapp.com:80/endpoint`
8. `wss://ourapp.com:8080/endpoint`
9. `wss://ourapp.com:8084/endpoint`
10. `wss://ourapp.com:443/endpoint`

None of the above open a connection. What are we missing here?

PS: I have set up a test ground: http://vakuutustiedot-dev.herokuapp.com/websocket.test.html (the URI is `PROTOCOL:vakuutustiedot-dev.herokuapp.com:PORT/trial`)

The target app runs in a Heroku Apache Tomcat 8.5.38.
What comes to the port number, I am not sure how to get one.

Comment: I guess you are aware of the related [`documentation`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos). What kind of dyno are we talking about and how did you configure it?

Comment: @second Hobby web dynos. The Procfile: `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar $PORT target/*.war` If you need more info in order to diagnose the issue, let me know! :-)

Comment: `ourapp.com` sounds like an `inbound request` to me which workers can not handle. I think you have to use `Private Space Networking` and use the appropriate IP Addresses.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what WebSocket server you are using? How is it configured? Can you bring up a basic heroku endpoint with just the WS for testing?

Comment: do and echo $PORT and see what's there?

Comment: whats the frontend built with? Is it angular by any chance?

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni I am not quite literate with what comes to Heroku. Tried ot Google $PORT up without results.

Comment: @StanWiechers I added some information on my set up.

Comment: From what I can see the url should be 'wss://vakuutustiedot-dev.herokuapp.com/endpoint` (don't worry about the port, heroku only works on 80/443 defaults), so locally you use 'wss://localhost:YOURLOCALPORT/endpoint' right?

Comment: @coderodde did you try my solution???

Comment: @Maurice The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have missed adding the support of WebSockets to Heroku, like in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002416/11197115)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try configuring the `proxy` attribute of `devServer`. This attribute is used when the frontend app and backend api are not running on the same host. Perhaps the below setting might solve your problem.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'ws://ourapp.com:8080/endpoint'
  }
}
```

For more info see the docs: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver

Comment: I don't use Vue.js.

Comment: @coderodde check the comment you've placed under your own post. it says `The frontend is built with Vue.js`