# Simple web java app works with heroku local web, but when deployed it crashes

Tags: java, web, heroku, deployment

I'm using maven 3 and JDK8 in my web java app. When I run it with heroku local web it works just fine. The deployment of the app works fine too, but when I try to access any route I get this error message:

```
2019-11-16T16:18:12.213730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-16T16:18:14.828031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=5000 -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Server`
2019-11-16T16:18:16.737715+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2019-11-16T16:18:16.741192+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2019-11-16T16:18:16.852336+00:00 app[web.1]: Servidor à espera de ligações no porto 5000
2019-11-16T16:19:45.407156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-16T16:19:45.285183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2019-11-16T16:19:45.285183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-11-16T16:19:45.382598+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-11-16T16:22:20.485432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sd-back-end.herokuapp.com request_id=6b2ff817-990a-4b10-bd4d-fb2a929ea1fc fwd="149.90.124.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-16T16:22:20.951050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sd-back-end.herokuapp.com request_id=894ab47b-a10d-4467-84b3-7ed824b6ff7c fwd="149.90.124.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=5000 -cp target/classes;target/dependency/* Server
```

The code of this app: https://github.com/EDUnter/SD_Server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751071/heroku-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-90-seconds-of-launch-tootall/36751552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `-Dserver.port=5000` with `-Dserver.port=$PORT`.

For more information see [Setting the HTTP Port for Java Applications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications)